# Angularjs - Extending ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Afternoon,

ngModelController gives you control over `$dirty` and `$pristine` but I would like to have my own one. How would I go about extending the ngModelController to offer something like `ngModelCtrl.$setCustom()`?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend `ngModelDirective`, but what you can do is create your own `ng-model`. It's a relatively unknown thing in Angular that you can have multiple directives with the same name, and all of them will be executed. Here's a JSBin with an example:
http://jsbin.com/nopoyiso/1/edit

And for those who can't be bothered opening the JSBin:

```
myApp.directive('ngModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.setCustom = function() {
        console.log('hello!');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So this is a way to do it, but I think you'll end up confusing both yourself and others by doing this. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Perhaps there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: When you access the input from the form object you can if it is dirty or pristine. I want to add a custom state such as "blurred "

Comment: Then I guess you could do it like in the JSBin I created. It would be a bit clearer if you created your own directive instead of calling your directive `ng-model`, but then you'd have to add both your directive and `ng-model` to your inputs. So I guess it's up to you to decide what feels best.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't realise props set on the model controller would be available via the form controller.

Comment: Yeah that's a power of Javascript, that you can augument any object you want to. But it's also something you should avoid doing when you can because it can be hard to find the code that auguments other objects.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl why does the jsbin link differ drastically from the code snippet?