# What happens when you redeclare an existing directive in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The question arises from reading [this source code](https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified/blob/master/src/directive/ngModel.js). What happens when `ngModel` is redeclared in line 7? And how does the pre-existing `ngModel` continue to function even as the new one works?

I'm looking to understand what the angular framework does with directives, and how that behaviour enables such redeclaration.

Comment: comments will help me understand why the question is being downvoted. Also, if the real answer is too broad, links to existing documentation touching the topic will suffice. So far I have failed to find any, hence I turn to stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you have asked a good question. I was surprised when I learned that the AngularJS framework doesn't replace the old directive. It adds to it.

Comment: @jrharshath would this be better titled "What happens when you redefine the core ng-model directive" ? It is a great question though.

Comment: @jrharshath So if u require the ng-model and access ngModel.NgModelController is it just manipulating the pre-existing one? One person stated you cannot extend it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454897/angularjs-extending-ngmodel  But that seems exactly what the code is doing in ur link.

Comment: [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) explains what happens when directives share the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register two directives with the same name, the second one won't redeclare the old one, neither will it add to it. There will simple be two different directives with the same name.

Consider you add three directives named `test`. If you want to inspect the queue they are pushed into it's stored in the `_invokeQueue` property of your module object.

Doing the following:

```
<pre>{{ app._invokeQueue | json }}</pre>
```

Will generate:

```
[
  [
    "$compileProvider",
    "directive",
    {
      "0": "test"
    }
  ],
  [
    "$compileProvider",
    "directive",
    {
      "0": "test"
    }
  ],
  [
    "$compileProvider",
    "directive",
    {
      "0": "test"
    }
  ]
]
```

If you do `console.log(app._invokeQueue)` you can inspect it further.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xzz7ASHYNUxk71QaJTQV?p=preview

*The demo also shows in what order the compile, pre- and post-linking functions are executed (check the console).*

If you add a custom directive named `ngModel` the two directives can live their own lives, but you still "extend" the original, at least in one way.

Since if you have the following:

```
<input ng-model="viewModel.person" />
```

Both directives will get executed and you have "extended" the behavior of ng-model.

Then add the fact that your custom `ngModel` directive can require and access the controller of the original `ngModel` directive and you will get even more options on how to affect the original behavior.

If you can extend the original `ngModel` or not might come down to how you define "extend".